# An annotation can't be used as the annotations argument

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I get a error, although do exactly the same that documentation says. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#many-to-many):

```
data class PlaylistWithSongs(
    @Embedded val playlist: Playlist,
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "playlistId",
         entityColumn = "songId",
         associateBy = @Junction(PlaylistSongCrossRef::class)
    )
    val songs: List<Song>
)
```

My problem:

[image: Error]

```
data class FileEntryWithTags(
        @Embedded val fileEntry: FileEntry,
        @Relation(
                parentColumn = FileEntry.COLUMN_UUID,
                entityColumn = Tag.COLUMN_ID,
                associateBy = @Junction(FileEntryTagCrossRef::class)
        )
        val tags: List<Tag>
)
```

Comment: Very interesting issue - following this to see the resolution and see if this is a mistake in the developer docs.

Comment: @Ryan It's a mistake in the Android documentation. The Kotlin reference makes it clear that `@` should not prefix the annotation name in this context.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like the Android documentation has a mistake in it. The [Annotations - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html) page from the Kotlin reference tells us:

> If an annotation is used as a parameter of another annotation, its name is not prefixed with the `@` character:
>
> ```kotlin
> annotation class ReplaceWith(val expression: String)
>
> annotation class Deprecated(
>         val message: String,
>         val replaceWith: ReplaceWith = ReplaceWith(""))
>
> @Deprecated("This function is deprecated, use === instead", ReplaceWith("this === other"))
> ```

So your code should be:

```kotlin
data class FileEntryWithTags(
        @Embedded val fileEntry: FileEntry,
        @Relation(
                parentColumn = FileEntry.COLUMN_UUID,
                entityColumn = Tag.COLUMN_ID,
                associateBy =  Junction(FileEntryTagCrossRef::class)
        )
        val tags: List<Tag>
)
```

Comment: You are right. It is mistake in Android Room documentation. All work fine without `@`.

Comment: If you came to this page because the Android room changelog had bugs, the correct code is here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions