# @Index annotation leads to "This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property with backing field'"

Tags: kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create an index on a foreign key using the `@Index` annotation. Unfortunately, the compiler complains with the following message:

```
This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property with backing field'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
class MyEntity(someValue: Long) : BaseEntity(someValue) {

    // .. some fields
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "another_entity")
    @Index(name = "ix_another_entity")
    var anotherEntity: AnotherEntity? = null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Index` cannot be used like this (neither in java nor in kotlin), instead you can use it e.g. as part of the `@Table` annotation:

```
@Table(name= "my_entity", indexes = [ Index(columnList = "another_entity") ])
```

[Specifying an Index (Non-Unique Key) Using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405229/specifying-an-index-non-unique-key-using-jpa)

(note that e.g. MySQL auto creates an index for foreign keys: [Does MySQL index foreign key columns automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304317/does-mysql-index-foreign-key-columns-automatically) )

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately, this didn't work. Now the compiler complains with: `An annotation can't be used as the annotations argument`. Any idea?

Comment: this looks like a kotlin specific issue, annotation arguments must not have the leading @; https://stackoverflow.com/a/62113971

Comment: Been there, done that, did not work! `An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant`

Comment: how exactly does your complete @Table annotation look like?

Comment: `@Table(name = "my_entity", indexes = { Index(columnList = "another_entity") })`

Comment: pleasy try with the array literal syntax: `indexes = [ Index(columnList="anotherEntity") ]`